# Is it possible to add a string to the result using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code:

```
// connect and select the database
$smt = $db->query(" SELECT 'one' which, col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col1 = '10'
                       UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'two' which, col1, col2 FROM table2 WHERE col1 = '10'
                    ");

while($result = $smt->fetch())  {
    if($result['which'] == 'one'){
        $result['col1'] = 'String: '.$result['col1'];
    }
}
```

As you see in the above code, there is an `IF()` statement for combining a string with the result of `col1` (just for `table1`). Now I want to know, is it possible to I do that using MySQL? (At the moment I do that using PHP)

In other word, can I do this in MySQL?

```
if($result['which'] == 'one'){
    $result['col1'] = 'String: '.$result['col1'];
}
```

Comment: Yes, case statement. Search it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos emm, yeah, I think I can do that using `Case` statement, thanks

Comment: Use [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) and [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) like so: `IF(which = "one", CONCAT("String: ", col1), col1) AS col1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what string you want to put in front of the first column of the first select statement, and it's not dynamic, then you can just concatenate the string you want in front of the first column:

```
$smt = $db->query("SELECT CONCAT('String:',col1), col2 FROM table1 WHERE col1 = '10'
                   UNION ALL
                SELECT CONCAT('String2: ',col1), col2 FROM table2 WHERE col1 = '10'
                ");
```

Comment: wow, it works correctly, really I'm wonder, because there is not any condition! +1upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can add a fixed string to your query results using the CONCAT fuction: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

In your example I think what you're after is `CONCAT('String: ', col1)`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use CASE and CONCAT. Try something like below

```
 $smt = $db->query(" SELECT 'one'which, CASE( WHEN (which = 'one') THEN CONCAT('String:',which) ELSE col1 END) as col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col1 = '10'
                   UNION ALL
                SELECT 'two' which, CASE( WHEN (which = 'two') THEN CONCAT('String:',which) ELSE col1 END) as col1, col2 FROM table2 WHERE col1 = '10'
                ");
```

Comment: please remove `,` after `'one'` in the first query

Comment: Done and be carefull with `as col1` it the string gets concatenated, then `WHERE col1 =10` will not work. Give it some other name.

Comment: ah ok! +1 upvote for you. (however `CASE() THEN` is additional overhead.)